# How to pass a call back delegate to a dll in .netCF

Tags: c#

I am writing a .netCF application that interfaces to a barcode scanner on different hardware platforms.  I. E. Motorola or Intermec Etc.  I have wrapped their DLLs with one of my own to present a common interface and I am loading my dll at runtime with Reflection LoadFrom() and then get a Method reference.

I am able pass most parameters to the methods in my dll with one exception.  I need to pass a call back function to the dll so that when a read occurs it will call back into the main program to process the barcode read.

When I invoke the method it throws an ArgumentException.

My question is how do I pass this method reference to my dll or is there a better way to do this?

```
    public delegate void ReadNotify(BCReadData readData);

    public void AttachReadNotify(ReadNotify ReadNotifyHandler)
    {
        if (type == ReaderType.UNKNOWN || scanIntf == null)
            return;
        try
        {
           setReadNotify.Invoke(scanIntf,new Object [] {ReadNotifyHandler});
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to set notify handler" + e.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: How does your native method's signature look like?

Answer (score 0):

If your native callback uses the __stdcall calling convention, you can accomplish this using the [Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate.aspx) method.